# BTYD (Buy 'Till You Die). Walkthrough. pnbd.EstimateParameters()

Tags: r, statistics

This is the first time I am working on BTYD procedure. I am having errors running the parameter estimates. I have provided the error message below. I have been following the [BTYD - Walkthrough](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf).

Does anybody know how to fix this? I worked through the sample data set and it works fine. I uploaded my file in the same format, it wouldn't work. There are no missing or empty rows/values. Help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
end.of.cal.period <- as.Date("2013-08-18")
elog.cal <- elog[which(elog$date <= end.of.cal.period), ]

split.data <- dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans(elog.cal);
clean.elog <- split.data$repeat.trans.elog; 
#clean.elog
freq.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(clean.elog); 
freq.cbt[1:3,1:5]

tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog.cal) #used elog.cal instead of elog
cal.cbt <- dc.MergeCustomers(tot.cbt, freq.cbt)
  
birth.periods <- split.data$cust.data$birth.per
last.dates <- split.data$cust.data$last.date
cal.cbs.dates <- data.frame(birth.periods, last.dates, end.of.cal.period)
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates,per="week") #works. no errors
head(cal.cbs, n=10)

sel <- cbind(cal.cbs)
colnames(sel) <-c('x', 't.x', 'T.cal')
head(sel, n=10)

params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(sel)
```

> Error in optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value
> = max.param.value,  :
> L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that when estimating the parameters, large values in sel$x will cause the exponentiation to blow up and error.

This guy has a fix on github here: https://github.com/theofilos/BTYD

I basically took all of his code in [pnbd.R](https://github.com/theofilos/BTYD/blob/master/pnbd.R), and prepend it to my code for the Pareto/NBD analysis and it seems to fix that issue.

Comment: I tried this as well and I am still getting the error, could you all fix yours?

Comment: Oh, I did my own fix to this. I realized that the hyperbolic functions in it might get too big numbers so it crashes, one needs to monitor this and take some measures when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the starting parameters? They default to 1,1,1,1. Something like:

```html
startingparams <- c(.1, 3, .1, .1)
params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(sel, startingparams)
```

Play with different orders of magnitude and see if any stick. Alternatively, check your maximum 'x' value in the cbs matrix. If there are extreme outliers you may want to remove them and try estimating the parameters again.