# BTYD pnbd.EstimateParameters(): cal.cbs must have a frequency column labelled "x"

Tags: r, model, statistics

I am working on building a CLV model. I have faced an error, but answers to [sharp's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429008/btyd-buy-till-you-die-walkthrough-pnbd-estimateparameters) helped in resolving it. Now, when I try and estimate the parameters using

```
params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs)
```

I get an error

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Error in pnbd.cbs.LL: cal.cbs must have a frequency column labelled "x"
```

I tried comparing the cal.cbs I have with the one in the [BTYD Walkthrough](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf). The headers and format are the same.
I looked at the source code for pnbd.EstimateParameters but can't figure out where the problem lies.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you must have your frequency column named `x` in your `cal.cbs` variable which is also what the error msg says.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @chinsoon12. The cal.cbs derived from the walkthrough has the frequency column as t.x - same as mine.

Comment: try renaming t.x to x and run again